# Override 302 response in WebLogic

Tags: java, web-applications, servlets, weblogic

When I do a redirect inside J2EE web application deployed on WebLogic it sends back to the client the following response:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Cache-Control: no-cache="set-cookie"
Date: Sat, 12 Dec 2009 07:37:43 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Location: http://server:port/front/page
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=CDdjLjLHSLlGxzzBT7dmLCw7JFZyBTxp95gJyxSL8GLS2gpNGKpb!1582307085; path=/
X-Powered-By: Servlet/2.4 JSP/2.0

01d7
<html><head><title>302 Moved Temporarily</title></head>
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<p>This document you requested has moved temporarily.</p>
<p>It's now at <a href="http://server:port/front/page">http://server:port/front/page</a>.</p>
</body></html>

0000
```

Is there a way to override that HTML?

Comment: Are you redirecting from HTTPs to HTTP? I've never seen this page. What version of weblogic is that?

Comment: Weblogic 9.2. And it's HTTP redirect. I used Fiddler to get raw HTTP request/response and the 302 response contains that HTML inside.

Comment: Your comment helped a lot and it would be really nice to update your question with it. However, something is still unclear: what URL ([protocol]://[ip]:[port]/) is exactly expected?

Comment: The expected URL is /front/page.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the web.xml of your application to override it, like:

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>302</error-code>
    <location>/error302.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

EDIT:
The error page may start with:

```
<%@ page language="java" isErrorPage="true" %>
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/fmt.tld" prefix="fmt" %>
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/c.tld" prefix="c" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
...
```

Regards.

Comment: Do you have an example of such JSP? That will insert the redirected URLs correctly?

Comment: @Pascal - and why not?  Admittedly it won't normally be displayed in a typical web browser.  But there are other use-cases for HTTP!

Comment: @Atorras, but how would you get the URL that 302 response is redirecting to?

Comment: The HttpServletResponse object has a sendRedirect() method you could use to redirect the request (inside the error302.jsp or inside some controller). Example: response.sendRedirect("correctLocation.jsp")

Comment: There is no big sense in that as it will be recursively hitting the same page :).

Answer (score 0):

My initial problem was related to absolute URLs in the 302 response. And I have found that absolute URL is dictated by [HTTP specification](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.30). Even though most browsers tolerate relative URLs, that's not a reliable solution anyway. That means that overriding 302 response will not give me the desired result in all possible situations. I would rather use the solution proposed by Pascal or make Apache additional configuration for URL rewrite engine.